# how to add any hash to empty array of hashes?

Tags: crystal-lang

I just learn Crystal, but stuck on an array of mix type hashes.

Suppose there is an array of hashes:

```
array = [{"a" => "Aa", "b" => 66, "c" => Time.now}]
```

I can easily add another element:

```
array << {"c" => "Bb", "d" => 2, "f" => 1.year.from_now}
```

But when I start from the empty array:

```
empty = [] of Hash(String, String | Time | Int64)
```

and try to add new element, an error appears:

```
empty << {"a" => "Aa", "b" => 66, "c" => Time.now}
# no overload matches 'Array(Hash(String, Int64 | String | Time))#<<' 
# with type Hash(String, Int32 | String | Time)
```

Could you please explain what I do wrong?

Link to [sample code](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/617p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little mistake. You defined hash with `String, Int64 | String | Time` but trying to add hash with `String, Int32 | String | Time`.

Just change `Int64` to `Int32` and this will be work, see fixed example — https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6185

Comment: thank's a lot. i printed out both typeofs and stared at them, and didn't notice that.

Comment: It happens... Good luck in learning Crystal, it is a beautiful language.